# How to prevent GDB from loading debugging symbol for a (large) library?

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, shared-libraries, debug-symbols

While debugging a Qt 5 application, I am sometimes not interested in the internals of Qt 5 but in the structure of the application itself. Therefore I do not need to load all debugging symbols of the Qt 5 libraries since these take a few seconds to load.

Is it possible to prevent GDB from loading symbols for these Qt 5 libraries while keeping the debugging symbols for my application?

Comment: Maybe this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_gdb_on_wimpy_computers  might be of some use.

Comment: @RichardCritten The link is broken.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it possible to prevent GDB from loading symbols for these Qt 5 libraries while keeping the debugging symbols for my application?

Yes.

As Richard Critten's comment mentions, setting [`auto-solib-add`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-set-auto_002dsolib_002dadd-1169) to `0` will prevent loading of symbols for *all* shared libraries, and you can then add files manually with the [`sharedlibrary`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-sharedlibrary-1176) command (which accepts a regex). If this regex is omitted, then all shared libraries are loaded.

That however would prevent auto-loading of *all* symbols (not just debug symbols), and would also prevent auto-loading of symbols for system libraries, which are often required to unwind the stack.

A better approach may be to save a copy of Qt5 libraries with full debug info somewhere, e.g. `~/Qt5-debug/`, then run `strip -g` on the original libraries. That way, you will get symbolic info for all libraries, and in the rare case when you actually need full-debug info for Qt5, you can still do that using the GDB `file ~/Qt5-debug/libQt5Core.so.5.2` or similar commands.

The chapter [GDB Files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB-Files.html#GDB-Files) from the GDB manual has more documentation on using such separate debugging symbols.

Comment: Thanks rubber duck! Shortly after posting this question I found the relevant sections in the GDB manual, hopefully you do not mind me adding them :-)

Comment: Great thanks!!! Start debugging of Qt app on the Raspberry takes a really long time. With this option starting gdb occurs instantly.

Comment: You can also add this exact command to ~/.gdbinit to make it permanent.

Comment: how do i prevent a library from loading with sharedlibrary regex

Comment: @PMat Specify a regex that doesn't match the library you don't want to load?

Comment: @EmployedRussian I want to specify exclude a specific lib, example: exclude libboost_thread.so, it only seems to take matches not negations