# Debugging Qt applications without loading Windows DLLs

Tags: debugging, gdb, qt-creator

How can you run a program in the Qt debugger without waiting for it to load debugging information for every dependent DLL?

- Create a Qt Widgets application in Qt Creator
- Press F5 to run with debugging

Instead of starting immediately, we wait for the IDE to load debugging info for msctf.dll, api-ms-win-crt-runtime.dll, wlanutil.dll, ddraw.dll, atigktxx.dll, and many other components which we're not interested in debugging the internals of.

Similarly, when the application displays a "file-open" dialog box, we have to wait for comctl32.dll, IconCodecService.dll, SearchFolder.dll, WMASF.dll and many others to be loaded, even though we won't be debugging those.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this answer for linux should work for you on windows as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41025900/72178

If you want to completely skip all debugging information from all DLLs you can do this before running the binary in gdb:

```
(gdb) set auto-solib-add off
```